# Fixing RANX's strange behaviour?

Tags: powerbi

Just started learning Power BI.  With sample sales data, trying to rank countries based on their total revenue.

With this DAX `Rank = RANKX(ALL(Territories[Country]),SUM('Sales'[Revenue]))`. I get
[image]

But when I create a Measure `Total Revenue = SUM('Sales'[Revenue])` and use it in DAX `Rank = RANKX(ALL(Territories[Country]),[Total Revenue])`, I get proper results.  Just wondering what is it that I am missing that gives different results.

[image]

Comment: The concept you are missing is https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-context-transition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measures are automatically wrapped in CALCULATE to force a context transition, transforming the row scope into a filter scope.  So the equivalent of

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL(Territories[Country]),[Total Revenue])
```

is

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL(Territories[Country]),CALCULATE(SUM('Sales'[Revenue])))
```

Without CALCULATE the sum is performed for each Country, but without a filter on Country, so all the rows calculate the global sum.  This is just like using Sum in a calculated column.

You can also use the row scope without a context transition like this:

```
Rank = RANKX(ALL(Territories[Country]),sumx(relatedtable('Sales'),[Revenue]))
```

Comment: Briliant!  Much clearer now.